# Java 7 ForkJoin freezes when it has to fork

Tags: java, java-7, fork-join

**Background:** I'm running simulations of escape panic, how people escape from rooms, buildings corridors etc. For large populations there is a large number of computation as each person needs to calculate a "social force" from each other person (i.e. 2000 people = 2000^2 calculations)

**Code:** I tried to implement a fork join mechanism to split this calculation. "people" is an array list of class "Pedestrian". Each person in my simulation is an instance of this class. This is the function in which I implemented the frok/join:

```
public static void timeSteppBridgeAllMulti() {
    counterIteration++;
    MultiThreading mt = new MultiThreading(0, people.size());
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    pool.invoke(mt);

}

static class MultiThreading extends RecursiveAction {

    int mStart = 0;
    int mLength = 0;

    MultiThreading(int start, int length) {
        mStart = start;
        mLength = length;
    }

    protected void computeDirectly() {
        for (int i = mStart; i < mStart + mLength; i++) {
            people.get(i).timeStepBridge();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (people.size() <= 300) {//do work directly
            computeDirectly();
            return;
        }

        int split = people.size() / 2;
        invokeAll(new MultiThreading(mStart, split), new MultiThreading(mStart + split, people.size()));
    }
}
```

For each person (people.get(i)) I call the timeStepBridge function which loops over all other people, reads their position and calculates the distance and the force to them.

**Problem:** When the number of people is less than the threshold (here 300), the program runs without problem. However, when the number of people exceeds the threshold the program throws a java.lang.StackOverflowError. I increased the Stack size and then the program just freezes and does not respond.

I've played around with this for a couple of days but cannot get anywhere. If anybody has an idea I would appreciate it

Comment: What OS are you running this in?  Many times, the OS has the limitation on the number of process being forked.

Comment: I'm running Windows 7, 64-bit. I tried to get this running with 301 people so it should just fork once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly split the work in your `RecursiveAction`.

Your `RecursiveAction` works with slice of `people` of length `mLength`, it should not call `people.size()` at all:

```
@Override
protected void compute() {
    if (mLength <= 300) {//do work directly
        computeDirectly();
        return;
    }

    int split = mLength / 2;
    invokeAll(
        new MultiThreading(mStart, split), 
        new MultiThreading(mStart + split, mLength - split));
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now that you say it seems obvious. sorry for the useless question